# Path name in google cloud run for Piscina

Tags: node.js, server, cloud, google-cloud-run

I'm added Piscina to my Node JS server, locally it works but when I upload the file to google cloud run, it's taking the directory that I specify in my Dockerfile.

In node js I use:

```
 const piscina = new Piscina({
        filename: path.resolve("./") + '/workers/send_payment_by_mail_worker.js'
    });

const result = piscina.runTask({_data: this.data});
```

In the index.js file I can use:

```
const piscina = new Piscina({
    filename: path.resolve( __dirname + '/workers/send_payment_by_mail_worker.js')
});
```

Which prints out the correct location where the file is located.
In my dockerfile I have :

```
   FROM node:12.18.1

WORKDIR /

COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Google cloud run takes / as main directory. How do you need to configure that cloud run takes the correct file directory for location the file for Piscina?

The error that I receive is:

```
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726607ZError [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/services/action/workers/send_payment_by_mail_worker.js' imported from /node_modules/piscina/dist/src/worker.js
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726628Z at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:284:11)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726636Z at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:665:10)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726642Z at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:755:11)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726648Z at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726654Z at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726660Z at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:28)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726666Z at importModuleDynamically (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1081:27)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726671Z at exports.importModuleDynamicallyCallback (internal/process/esm_loader.js:37:14)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726678Z at eval (eval at getImportESM (/node_modules/piscina/dist/src/worker.js:37:27), <anonymous>:1:16)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726684Z at getHandler (/node_modules/piscina/dist/src/worker.js:58:39)
Default
2020-11-27T07:56:31.726919ZuncaughtException
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the error that you are getting and which line of code is causing it? You mentioned this working locally, have you tried running the docker image without cloud run ?

Comment: I updated the ticket. I tested this with docker image on localhost, then I don't have the issue. Do I need to specify a working directory somewhere? Or how can this directory be found on GCR?

Comment: I believe the line `filename: path.resolve("./") + '/...worker.js'` should be `filename: path.resolve("./", '/....worker.js')`, extra parenthesis there, I followed the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) of cloud run and at the bottom of the index.js I added the example code of the piscina repo [readme](https://github.com/piscinajs/piscina) and worked ok, my index.js and worker.js are in root dir, no errors in cloud run, if its not the parenthesis maybe something is happening with the directory structure, afaik no working dir in cloud run is needed

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working. Is there any trick so this can work on localhost aswell? For localhost it's the other way (path.resolve("./") + '/...worker.js')